# Trying to read from switches and output in a LED switch board

Tags: assembly, mips

I am wrtiing a program in PLP assembly that repeatedly reads the value of the switches (address: `0xf0100000`) and displays a pattern on the LED array (address: `0xf0200000`) based on what switches are clicked. Each time the switch value is read, the pattern should be displayed (regardless of whether the switch value has changed or not since the last time it was read).

The outputs are supposed to be the following:

```
0: Flash all LEDS
1: Flash all even numbered LEDS
2: Flash all odd numbered LEDS
3: Cycle through each numbered LED one by one
Other Switch: Turn off all LEDS
```

I have written the following code according to my pseudocode notes and it should work. It assembles and runs, but there is no LED output when any switches are pressed. At first I thought not including the `nop` after each break might be the issue but this didn't change anything.

Does anyone see any errors?

```
# main source file

.org 0x10000000


li $t0, 0xf0100000 #Switch adrress
li $t1, 0xf0200000 # LED adress
Loop1:
    lw $t2, 0($t0)       
    li $t3, 0x00000001 #Checks if 1 pressed
    beq $t2, $t3, case1 #Then sends to case1

    lw $t2, 0($t0)
    li $t3, 0x00000002 #2 presssed
    beq $t2, $t3, case2 #sends to case 2

    lw $t2, 0($t0)
    li $t3, 0x00000004 #3 pressed 
    beq $t2, $t3, case3 #sends to case 3

    lw $t2, 0($t0)
    li $t3, 0x00000008 #4 pressed
    beq $t2, $t3, case4 #sends to case 4

    li $t3, 0x00000000
    sw $t3, 0($t1)
j Loop1
nop

case1:
    li $t3, 0x000000ff
    sw $t3, 0($t1)
    li $t3, 0x00000000
    sw $t3, 0($t1)
j Loop1
nop

case2:
    li $t3, 0x00000055
    sw $t3, 0($t1)
    li $t3, 0x00000000
    sw $t3, 0($t1)
j Loop1
nop

case3:
    li $t3, 0x000000aa
    sw $t3, 0($t1)
    li $t3, 0x00000000
    sw $t3, 0($t1)
j Loop1
nop

case4:
    li $t3, 0x00000001
    sw $t3, 0($t1)
    li $t3, 0x00000002
    sw $t3, 0($t1)
    li $t3, 0x00000004
    sw $t3, 0($t1)
    li $t3, 0x00000008
    sw $t3, 0($t1)
    li $t3, 0x00000010
    sw $t3, 0($t1)
    li $t3, 0x00000020
    sw $t3, 0($t1)
    li $t3, 0x00000040
    sw $t3, 0($t1)
    li $t3, 0x00000080
    sw $t3, 0($t1)
j Loop1
nop
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that the problem is mainly related to the time during which your leds are on. I do not know what is the frequency of your system but admitting that it is 10Mhz, the duration during which your leds will be on is counted in ms.
In your code the lw $ t2, 0 ($ t0) are redundant I think. the nops too.

A basic way to insert delay is by using a loop like:

```
li $t4, val
wait_x:
   addi $t4, $t4, -1
   bgtz $t4, wait_x
```

you need to find the val that match the performances of your system. If it still too fast you can add some nops in the loop.

Comment: I agree that the program is going to execute too fast to see changes.  Some "delay" or timing operations need to be inserted or else some other default behaviors (like do nothing instead of clearing if no button is pressed).

Comment: Do you have any idea of commands which would solve this issue? nothing like that has ever been covered in my course.